# Item analysis with small sample size

Tags: item-analysis

I gave a 12 item true-false quiz (which I created) to my 19 students.

I noticed that some questions were very obviously easier than others, so I decided to run an item analysis. By looking at the item difficulty results, it does seem like that's the case. I am thinking of re-administering the quiz and excluding items with item difficulty below 0.5.

But with such a small sample size, should I even bother with item analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this sample size (and number of items/questions), any statistical analysis would be questionable. However, from a purely descriptive perspective, the item analysis might suggest which are the easiest and the hardest. It probably would not let you do any more refined ranking of the item-difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Greg H that a sample size of $n=19$ is quite small$^1$. Also, because your data is both dichotomous and self-reported (i.e., students answer true/false; unlike other dichotomous items where students are scored as correct/incorrect), your sample size is even more limiting as guessing likely may add considerable noise to your results (i.e., if a student guesses, they have a 50/50 chance of a correct response).

$^1$See Bujang et al. Baharum (2018) and Cappelleri et al. (2014) for more information on sample size requirements for methods related to item analysis. For instance, both mention $n = 30$ as a commonly cited minimum sample size.

**References**

Bujang, M. A., Omar, E. D., & Baharum, N. A. (2018). A review on sample size determination for Cronbach’s alpha test: a simple guide for researchers. The Malaysian journal of medical sciences: MJMS, 25(6), 85.

Cappelleri, J. C., Lundy, J. J., & Hays, R. D. (2014). Overview of classical test theory and item response theory for the quantitative assessment of items in developing patient-reported outcomes measures. Clinical therapeutics, 36(5), 648-662.